# How to check if ps2 to usb adapter isnt malicious?

Tags: badusb

I got an adapter for free from someone in my city.

After googling the serial number I found it also here:

https://www.ebay.de/itm/MOUSE-ADAPTER-501215-B004-PS-2-TO-USB-CONVERTER-/331762184078

Can I check if there is a keylogger or something going on inside the device ?

Kind regards

Comment: Actually not, mmmh.

Comment: Explain what why doesn't it answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

The device you linked isn't subject to BadUSB as ... it's not USB !!!

Look at it ! It's designed to be plugged in a PS/2 ports.
PS/2 is only for basic, raw keyboards and mices.
See this description of PS/2 protocol for more details: http://www-ug.eecg.utoronto.ca/desl/nios_devices_SoC/datasheets/PS2%20Protocol.htm

I'm 99% confident that there's no malicious stuff inside that.

Comment: Although tagged with "badusb" the questions isn't specifically about badusb.